# How can teams collaborate on Unity 3D projects?

Tags: unity, project-management

With a friend of mine, we are planning to develop a small game to get the hang of game development and teamwork. But since Unity 3D barely supports version control (or at least the free version lacks of it) we have no idea how to efficiently manage teamwork. Sharing tasks in a small project is also seems like a challange for us.

I would also appreciate any advice that could be useful for beginner indie developers related to teamwork. :)